# synchronized methods in a Runnable

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, runnable

I am writing a Runnable class that's packing messages together for some time or until a given size is reached before sending them over the wire. It is designed to allow other threads to change some internal parameters (e.g. the packet size) while it is running via some setter methods.  Is it correct to use an internal object lock to make parts of the `run()` logic mutually exclusive with the setters?

Something like that:

```
public class Packer implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<byte[]> msgQueue;
    private Object lock = new Object();
    private Packet packet;
    private boolean running = false;

    public synchronized void append(byte[] payload) throws InterruptedException {
        msgQueue.put(payload);
    }

    public synchronized void setPacketCapacity(int size) {
        synchronized (lock) {
            // check to see if we need to flush the current packet first, etc.
            packet.setCapacity(size);
        }
    }
    public void run() {
        running = true;
        while (running) {
            try {
                byte[] msg = msgQueue.take();
                synchronized (lock) {
                    packet.add(msg);
                    // check if we need to flush the packet, etc.
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                logger.warn("interrupted");
                running = false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error(e);
            }
        }
        logger.warn("stop");
    }
}
```

Relatedly, what's the right way for another thread to tell this runnable to stop (and flush)?

Since the `run()` method might be waiting on the internal queue `msgQueue`, it might not be sufficient to simply set `running=false` and I might have to interrupt the thread.  Alternatively, I could send a special "End Of Stream" message to the internal queue, but if the queue is full I might have to wait for a while before it gets accepted.

Comment: I would not recommend overloading `interrupt()`.  That's for terminating a thread.

Comment: When you say "flush" do you mean "clear" or write to socket?

Comment: @Gray I try my best to be always diligent and accept answers that actually do answer my questions.

Comment: @Gray: when I say flush, I mean sending whatever might be in the packet, then clearing it.

Comment: Part of the issue @Pierre is that the questions/answers are for posterity -- not just for you.  You are doing SO a disservice by leaving around questions without answers.  Either answer them yourself, put a bounty on them, accept an answer (even if not perfect), edit them to provide more specificity or details, or delete them.

Comment: @Gray: re. not overloading `interrupt()`: good point; I should probably send some meta message through the queue instead, to get the `msgQueue.take()` to return and the `run()` method to handle it.

Comment: I think the synchronized should be removed from `append` and `setPacketCapacity`.

Comment: what is the purpose of synchronized (lock)? the lock object is not shared (private field)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you are locking your `setter` and the logic inside `run()` with one locking Object it is correct. I would suggest that you remove `synchronized` from setter method signature since you already lock all the code inside it with the locking Object
2. You can remove `boolean running` and write your `run()` like this:

   ```
   public void run() {
     while (true) {
       try {
           byte[] msg = msgQueue.take();
           synchronized (lock) {
               packet.add(msg);
               // check if we need to flush the packet, etc.
           }
       } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
           logger.warn("interrupted");
           Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
           return;
       } catch (Exception e) {
           logger.error(e);
       }
     }
     logger.warn("stop");
   }
   ```

Calling `thread.interrupt()` will force the code in `run()` method to go to the InterruptedException catch block where you set the interrupted flag and return from `run()`